Azure Search Integrated Vectorization Error
I've been using Azure AI Search for a while now and it has been running smoothly.
I use the 2023-10-01-preview for the AI Search to have access to the integrated vectorization feature. Vectorization is made through Azure OpenAI Embeddings and I authenticate using System assigned identities. The OAI service only allows access from dedicated VNets and services, however, the Search is included in it.
As I said, everything has worked fine until 2.4.24, coming back from easter holidays.
Now, I get the following error when running the search (also from the portal's search explorer view):
Could not complete vectorization action. The vectorization endpoint returned status code '403' (Forbidden).

The weirdest part is, that sometimes, when I open the Search Explorer and make a search, it works. Then, I run the same search again and the error pops up again.
When I deactivate vector search, it works of course.
Especially this flaky behavior that it does sometimes work, leaves me clueless, as I have not changed anything.
PS: The API-Version of the OpenAI-Service is 2024-02-01
This issue looks similar but I wouldn't understand how an API change would solve the issue. Also, 2023-11-01 doesn't use integrated vectorization so I guess the only reason it works for this user (in the answer at the bottom) is, because there is no call to vectorization at all.
Does anybody see the same problem in their setup?
Update: When I deactivate the VNet rules and allow public access, the Vectorization works again. I definititely didn't touch anything about the networking rules. Did Azure (Search) change something to the 31.3.24? IP-address updates that are not yet reflected in the Trusted Services rules?

Provide your indexer and skillset definition.

May be because of vnet rules you are getting error. kindly check it configure them.

We've identified this as an issue in the current version of the Search and AOAI service communication. Until this is fixed, we can suggest two workarounds:

Turn off trusted access in firewall rules

For a S2 service, use SPL (documentation: Connect through a shared private link - Azure AI Search) to connect to AOAI.
For a service that is not S2, add the search IP address to the AOAI firewall rules (documentation: Connect through firewalls - Azure AI Search)


[UPDATE] The underlying Azure OpenAI issue has been resolved, and search services should be able to reliably connect to Azure OpenAI without the workarounds described above when the fix is deployed in around a week.

Thanks for your workaround suggestion. I have been using your first proposal to deactivate it for a while.
Unfortunately, it is still not working for me. Maybe in an upcoming version, as Yuantao Wang has said above? Is there a public ticketing system where I could find the current status to this?

Sorry for the inaccurate info about the fix, I fixed my answer to reflect the correct deployment timing. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a public way of monitoring that, but please feel free to contact Azure support.

thanks, similar issue: https://serverfault.com/q/1162394/126950

The only workaround is to disable the vector search or enable public access on Azure OpenAI.

I enabled logging on Azure OpenAI and noticed that Azure AI Search is using the public IP 20.105.245.*. When I added this public IP to the Azure OpenAI firewall, the vector search in AI Search worked fine. My concerns are as follows:
1.  Why does the vector search use a public IP instead of a private endpoint, while all other functionalities work fine and use private endpoints?
2.  This public IP is different from the public IP attached to my AI Search instance. Is it shared with other AI Search instances?


Thank you for being a contributor to the Stack Overflow community. As a question and answer site, Stack Overflow works differently than most message boards. As such, kindly reserve the Answers feature for actual answers, not follow-up questions or comments.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
